# Server gives me a permission error when trying to scp, but not when ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, scp

Is there server configuration you need to set when you want to scp to a server?  If i ssh into the machine, i use:

```
ssh -i file.pem user@server
```

but when i try the scp command, it will give me a permissions error.

```
scp path/to/file.pdf -i file.pem user@server:/home/user/.
```

What am i doing wrong, and how can i fix it?  I cant seem to figure out what's up with it.  The error reads as:
`Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection`

Comment: Did you try moving the identity switch before the other args also you shouldnt need that trailing `.` if the last segement of the target is a dir it will copy the files into the directory: `scp -i file.pem path/to/file.pdf user@server:/home/user` Also you can use `-vvv` to get more verbose info on whats happening.

Comment: bingo!  thats it!  you need to put the -i file.pem before everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shuffle around your options and arguments. It should be:

```
scp -i file.pem path/to/file.pdf user@server:/home/user
```

Note the omission of `/.` from the end of the target path. It is not necessary because if the last segement of the target is a dir it will copy the files into the directory, just like `cp` and `mv`.

> Is there a way to assign the file.pem such that it just picks it up when i use: user

You can do that with an `~/.ssh/config` config file:

```
Host            serveralias
HostName        server.com
User            user
IdentityFile    /path/to/your/key.pem
```

After creating that you can do:

```
# will effectively be like doing 
# ssh -i /path/to/your/key.pem user@server.com
ssh serveralias
```

Or

```
# should pick up on the same settings and effectively like 
# ssh -i /path/to/your/key.pem user@server.com
ssh user@server.com
```

And they should both use the IdentityFile you specified.

Comment: I had a quick follow up question.  How come i dont need to do this with my regular server vs this one?   normally i do:  `ssh user@server`  Is there a way to assign the `file.pem` such that it just picks it up when i use: `user` ?

Comment: Yeah you can put it in your `~/.ssh/config` I do this with all the servers i access on a regular basis.

Comment: It seems that my config doesnt have anything involving pem's in it, unless you are talking about appending the .pems to `known_hosts` ?  Or would i just append all of them to the `config` file with a delimiter related to server seperating

Comment: My thought would be to do something in `known_hosts` like:   `host:server ssh_rsa data_goes_here`

Comment: I wasnt sure if there was a way to stack server perms inside of the `id_rsa` file.  I mean, i think i could just store all my pem files in that dir, and then in config, list all the hosts and data you listed.  I just wasnt sure how to segregate the different files since i have like 4 .pem files.

Comment: Look at the example in my updated answer. You would have one of those blocks for each `User@HostName` combination. And then it would use the values that match as options for the connection. the `Host` field is essentially an alias so you can just do things like `ssh production` or `ssh gateway`.

Comment: great.  thanks to know.  I guess i just need to list out all the blocks. :)